# How can I add a value to a row in pyspark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
preds.take(1)
[Row(_1=0, _2=Row(val1=False, val2=1, val3='high_school'))]
```

I want the whole thing to be one row, without the nested row in there. So, the first value would get a name and be a part of the one row object. If I wanted to name it "ID", it would look like this:

```
preds.take(1)
[Row(ID=0, val1=False, val2=1, val3='high_school')]
```

I've tried various things within a map, but nothing is producing what I'm looking for (or getting errors). I've tried:

```
preds.map(lambda point: (point._1, point._2))
preds.map(lambda point: point._2.append(point._1))
preds.map(lambda point: point._2['ID']=point._1)
preds.map(lambda point: (point._2).ID=point._1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `Row` is a `tuple` and `tuples` are immutable you can only create a new object. Using plain tuples:

```
from pyspark.sql import Row

r = Row(_1=0, _2=Row(val1=False, val2=1, val3='high_school'))
r[:1] + r[1]
## (0, False, 1, 'high_school')
```

or preserving `__fields__`:

```
Row(*r.__fields__[:1] + r[1].__fields__)(*r[:1] + r[1])
## Row(_1=0, val1=False, val2=1, val3='high_school')
```

In practice operating directly on rows should should be avoided in favor of using `DataFrame` DSL without fetching data to Python interpreter:

```
df = sc.parallelize([r]).toDF()

df.select("_1", "_2.val1", "_2.val2", "_2.val3")
```

Comment: The last option makes the most sense in my case. Didn't realize I should avoid operating on the rows themselves but that makes sense. Thank you!